# How to loop object in visual studio 3D

Tags: visual-studio

I run the code below in `display()` but the object `tree` didn't show. Anything wrong about the `for` loop? Do i need to put any header file to exucute **for** loop ?

```
tree(float f){
// CODE CREATED OBJECT,NO PROBLEM HERE
}

void display()
{
   for (int i=216;i>=317;i++)  //PROBLEM HERE,FOR LOOP NOT EXECUTED
   {
     glPushMatrix();
     glTranslated(i, 6.8, -5.3);
     glScaled(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
     tree(3.5); 
     glPopMatrix();

   }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);
glutInitWindowSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
glutCreateWindow("Unexpected Adventure");
initRendering();
glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutReshapeFunc(handleResize);
glutIdleFunc(idle);
glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
init();
initGL();
glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: this is missing a lot of context, but this loop is never executed since 216 is not >=317

Comment: thanks for comment but the i>=317 is the condition to stop the for loop right?

Comment: Hi Peter, you are right. Thanks for your answer =)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend always loop from 0 to `n` times, and do the math inside the loop

```
for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    float x = 216 + i;
    glTranslated(x, 6.8, -5.3);
    glScaled(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
    tree(3.5); 
    glPopMatrix();

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice =)

Comment: Your error is in `for (int i=216;i>=317;i++)`, which should be `for (int i=216;i<=317;i++)`